# Android - Manage click and longclick in listview

Tags: android, listview, click, onclicklistener, long-click

I am currently coding a new android Application, and I need to use both OnItemClickListener and OnItemLongClickListener on a listview. Each listener launch a different actionmode on the actionbar.
The problem is that the actionmode associated with the click event is the only that is launched even if I perform a longclick.
After some research, I understand now why : a long click event also create click event, and I guess that this last event is always perform after the long click event, so that explain why I can't manage to display the other actionmode.

The question is : how can I block the click event when i do a longclick ? Or does it exist another mean to perform what I want to do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`onLongClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html):

> Returns
>
> true if the callback consumed the long click, false otherwise.

So, if you return `true` the onclick won't be executed.

Comment: It was this simple ?? thank you very much !! I search on the net for 1h but i guess i didn't put the right words ^^